# using functions with variables from other python files at notebook's directory

Tags: python, function, variables, jupyter-notebook

For example, in my folder, I have my ipython notebook "program.ipynb" and a python file "functions.py" which has some functions in it, for example, "func"

```
from numpy import sqrt
def func(x):
    return N + sqrt(x)
```

that is going to be used in "program.ipynb" which looks like that

```
from functions import func
N = 5
func(2)
--> name 'N' is not defined
```

To fix the bug i need to define the variable N in my functions.py file but isn't there a way around? I want to define all my global variables in my main programm (program.ipynb).

Comment: Did you try `global N` then `N=5`. In general global variables are a bad practice as it gets harder to debug.

Comment: I tried _ global N _ ,  _ N=5 _  , _  func(2) _ and still got the same error

Comment: BTW: all variables created outside functions are global. We use word `global`  inside function (not outside) to inform function that we want to use external/global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access a variable like that, the best way would be:

functions.py

```
from numpy import sqrt
def func(x, N):
    return N + sqrt(x)
```

program.ipynb

```
from functions import func
N = 5
func(2, N)
```